# Laravel - disable dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

i have an dropdown which disabled using jquery like this :

```
$('#group_id_view').prop('disabled', true);
```

And it working only for view, but what i'm trying to do here is to disable the dropdown for user who had an `group_id`, so far here is what i have been trying :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
            if($(this).auth()->user()->group_id){
                    $('#group_id_edit').prop('disabled', true);
                }else{
                    $('#group_id_edit').prop('disabled', false);
                }
        });
```

And of course it still error, because i don't know how to check the `group_id` from jquery so that the dropdown will be disabled for users who had an `group id` and they cannot edit their own `group_id`, anyone has an solution to this? thank you!.

Comment: Why not disable using blade instead?

Comment: sorry that hasn't cross my mind yet, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Laravel Blade

```
<select id="group_id_edit" {{ (Auth::user()->group_id) ? 'disabled' : '' }}>
```